# unresolved external symbol __imp__RegDeleteTreeW@8

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have a static lib which is used by an exe without any problem.
In the same solution, there is an existing dll and I want to use some functions from my static lib. It compiles just fine but the linking fails with:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegDeleteTreeW@8 referenced in function
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__RegGetValueW@28 referenced in function
unresolved external symbol __imp__DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo@4 referenced in function
unresolved external symbol __imp__QueryDisplayConfig@24 referenced in function 
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes@12 referenced in function
```

Other call to MFC are linked just fine. My investigation so far showed me that this dll project has:

```
WINVER=0x0501
NTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WINXPSP1
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501
```

in preprocessor section
and as RegDeleteTree need at least 0x0601, I've changed the values to:

```
WINVER=0x0601
NTDDI_VERSION=NTDDI_WIN7
_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601
```

with no luck.

EDIT: using Visual Studio 2010 on Win 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deep in some old common properties files, there was a path to Microsoft\WinDDK\7600.16385.0\lib\wxp\i386

which is obviously XP lib, feeling so dumb right now

Answer (score 0):

Ensure Advapi32.lib is included in the link libraries of your DLL. See also [RegDeleteTree function on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379776%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) requirements section.

Comment: I can see /DLL "advapi32.lib" in the linker's command line section

Comment: That's correct. That's actually 2 separate arguments. `/DLL` tells the linker it's making a dll. `"advapi32.lib"` stands alone, telling the linker to add it to the output binary. Maybe it's not finding it in the library path.

Comment: I think it find the lib as RegOpenKeyEx seems to link just fine and is also in advapi32.lib. I have the problem only with functions which are available since Vista. But I'm Win 7. Using VS2010 by the way.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that it's linking an older version of advapi32.lib which doesn't have the new functions.

Comment: Yeah, but the exe links and runs fine, is there a way to tell the linker about this?

Comment: Does the exe actually call any of the unresolved functions? If it doesn't actually reference them, the linker won't look for them, and there won't be an error.

Comment: I'm not sure for RegDeleteTree but I'm sure for DisplayConfigGetDeviceInfo, QueryDisplayConfig and GetDisplayConfigBufferSizes are called both in the exe and the dll